# how to delete data from multiple table simultaneously SQLITE, ionic2

Tags: sqlite, ionic2

I have 2 tables in sqlite, ionic2. **user_master, user_packages** I am trying to delete all data from both tables simultaneously i.e., in single sql statement.
I am able to clear from 1 table but dont know how to do it from another table,

```
    deleteAllTablesSqlite() {
    this.db.openDatabase({//create table user_packages and store data in it
      name: 'cbsapp.db',
      location: 'default' // the location field is required
    }).then(() => {
      this.db.executeSql('DELETE from user_master', {}).then(() => {
        this.db.vacuum;
        console.log('TABLE deleted');
      }, (err:any) => {
        console.error('Unable to execute sql: ', err);
      });
    }, (err: any) => {
      console.error('Unable to open database: ', err);
    });//end then
  };//end deleteAllTablesSqlite()
```

Please guide me

1- Is there any way to drop both tables in sqlite, ionic2.

2- How to empty both tables in a single sql call or loop.

Thanks

Comment: Which do you want? - DROP (which will remove the table rendering it non existent) or DELETE (which will remove rows but keep the object) ?

Comment: preferebly DROP, I tried DROP TABLE if exists user_master, user_packages,  but it didnt work. I can only drop single table in one db.executeSql statement